# Supervisor fails to restart half of the time

Tags: debian, uwsgi, systemd, supervisord

I'm trying to deploy a Django app using Uwsgi and supervisor on a machine running Debian 8.1.

When I restart via `sudo systemctl restart supervisor` it fails to restart half of the time.

```
$ root@host:/# systemctl start supervisor
    Job for supervisor.service failed. See 'systemctl status supervisor.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
$ root@host:/# systemctl status supervisor.service
    ● supervisor.service - LSB: Start/stop supervisor
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/supervisor)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-09-23 11:12:01 UTC; 16s ago
      Process: 21505 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/supervisor stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 21511 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/supervisor start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Sep 23 11:12:01 host supervisor[21511]: Starting supervisor:
    Sep 23 11:12:01 host systemd[1]: supervisor.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
    Sep 23 11:12:01 host systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start/stop supervisor.
    Sep 23 11:12:01 host systemd[1]: Unit supervisor.service entered failed state.
```

However there is nothing in the supervisor or uwsgi logs.
Supervisor 3.0 is running with this configuration for uwsgi :

```
[program:uwsgi]
stopsignal=QUIT
command = uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
directory = /dir/
environment=ENVIRONMENT=STAGING
logfile-maxbytes = 300MB
```

stopsignal=QUIT has been added because UWSGI ignores the default signal (SIGTERM) on stop and gets killed brutally with SIGKILL leaving orphan workers.

Is there a way I could investigate what's happening ?

**EDIT:**

Tried as mnencia advised : `/etc/init.d/supervisor stop && while /etc/init.d/supervisor status ; do sleep 1; done && /etc/init.d/supervisor start`
but it still fails half of the time.

```
 root@host:~# /etc/init.d/supervisor stop && while /etc/init.d/supervisor status ; do sleep 1; done && /etc/init.d/supervisor start
    [ ok ] Stopping supervisor (via systemctl): supervisor.service.
    ● supervisor.service - LSB: Start/stop supervisor
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/supervisor)
       Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2015-11-24 13:04:32 UTC; 89ms ago
      Process: 23490 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/supervisor stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 23349 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/supervisor start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

    Nov 24 13:04:30 xxx supervisor[23349]: Starting supervisor: supervisord.
    Nov 24 13:04:30 xxx systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/stop supervisor.
    Nov 24 13:04:32 xxx systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start/stop supervisor...
    Nov 24 13:04:32 xxx supervisor[23490]: Stopping supervisor: supervisord.
    Nov 24 13:04:32 xxx systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start/stop supervisor.
    [....] Starting supervisor (via systemctl): supervisor.serviceJob for supervisor.service failed. See 'systemctl status supervisor.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
     failed!
    root@host:~# /etc/init.d/supervisor stop && while /etc/init.d/supervisor status ; do sleep 1; done && /etc/init.d/supervisor start
    [ ok ] Stopping supervisor (via systemctl): supervisor.service.
    ● supervisor.service - LSB: Start/stop supervisor
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/supervisor)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2015-11-24 13:04:32 UTC; 1s ago
      Process: 23490 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/supervisor stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 23526 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/supervisor start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 24 13:04:32 xxx systemd[1]: supervisor.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 24 13:04:32 xxx systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start/stop supervisor.
Nov 24 13:04:32 xxx systemd[1]: Unit supervisor.service entered failed state.
Nov 24 13:04:32 xxx supervisor[23526]: Starting supervisor:
Nov 24 13:04:33 xxx systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start/stop supervisor.
[ ok ] Starting supervisor (via systemctl): supervisor.service.
```

Comment: Imho, you actually hit a bug. I've opened a [debian bug](http://bugs.debian.org/805920) about this issue

Comment: I've added a workaround to my reply

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not necessarily an error from supervisor. I see from your `systemctl status` output that `supervisor` is started through the sysv-init compatibility layer, so the failure could be in the `/etc/init.d/supervisor` script. It would explain the absence of errors in the supervisord logs.

To debug the init script, the easiest way is to add a `set -x` as first non-comment instruction in that file, and look in the `journalctl` output the trace of the script execution.

**EDIT:**

I've reproduced and debugged it on a test system with Debian Sid.

The issue is that the *stop* target of the supervisor init-script does not check if the daemon has been really terminated but only send a signal if the process exists. If the daemon process takes a while to shutdown, the subsequent *start* action will fail due to the dying daemon process, which is counted as already running.

I've opened a bug on Debian Bug Tracker: http://bugs.debian.org/805920

**WORKAROUND:**

You can workaround the issue with:

```
/etc/init.d/supervisor force-stop && \
/etc/init.d/supervisor stop && \
/etc/init.d/supervisor start
```

- `force-stop` will ensure the supervisord has been terminated (outside systemd).
- `stop` make sure systemd know it's terminated
- `start` starts it again

The `stop` after the `force-stop` is required otherwise systemd will ignore any subsequent `start` request. `stop` and `start` can be combined using `restart`, but here I've put both of them to show how it works.

Comment: That seems to explain what's happening. As you suggested an implementation of stop, could I use "/etc/init.d/supervisor force-stop" and "/etc/init.d/supervisor start" while the issue gets fixed. Seems acceptable even though the kill -9 seems a bit overkill when the kill -15 doesn't work.

Comment: You can set the `DODTIME` constant in `/etc/default/supervisor` file to a long enough time to be sure that the `kill -9` will not be issued. The default is 5 seconds.

Comment: It works like a charm ! 10 seconds seems like enough to terminate gracefully 100 busy workers.

Comment: I've been a bit too fast : force-stop->start doesn't start uwgsi, i don't know why but it's not started until I call restart.

Comment: Weird. Maybe you could try with `/etc/init.d/supervisor stop && while /etc/init.d/supervisor status ; do sleep 1; done && /etc/init.d/supervisor start` . This should not be different from what the `restart` action does plus some more waiting in the middle.

Comment: I tried it, edited the post since the output was too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: It is because systemd hijack the `/etc/init.d/supervisor status` call. You need to find another way to check if the process is alive.

Comment: The workaround doesn't work any more because it seems like a newer version of supervisor doesn't support the force-stop command any more.

Comment: AFAIR the https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=805920 bug has been closed, so if you use a recent supervisord package it should work correctly. Otherwise please open another Debian bug

Comment: Yeah, I think simply using `/etc/init.d/supervisor restart` works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in ubuntu 14.04, tried the latest initd script from debian and @mnencia solution but they didn't worked for me. force-stop solution did not kill the program processes they just the kept running after supervisord was killed.

My solution was to patch the supervisord and start and restart parts of the initd script code I didn't want to guess a good DODTIME, I wanted it to be up as soon as the old supervisor master process dies, so I added a retry logic. Note that it's kinda verbose, but you can just remove the echo calls if you don't like that behavior and you can change the max reties (set to 20 here).

```
start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    i=1
    until [ $i -ge 21 ]; do
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS  && break
        echo -n -e "\nAlready running, old process still finishing? retrying ($i/20)..."
        let "i += 1"
        sleep 1
    done
sleep 1
    if running ; then
        echo "$NAME."
    else
        echo " ERROR."
    fi
;;
restart)
    echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE
    i=1
    until [ $i -ge 21 ]; do
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS  && break
        echo -n -e "\nAlready running, old process still finishing? retrying ($i/20)..."
        let "i += 1"
        sleep 1
    done
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
```

I also changed the hashbang (first line) so bash is used insted of sh, I wanted to use let

```
#! /bin/bash
```